# The nuget operation failed due to one or more packages being incompatible with your project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, nuget

I was trying to install the MathNet.Numerics package to my project (a class library), when I got this error:

The NuGet operation failed due to one or more packages being incompatible with your project. The '.NETPlatform,Version=v5.0' ('dotnet') project framework is deprecated. For more information about how to migrate your projects to a supported framework, please refer to themigration document (https://aka.ms/rugr4c). Would you like to continue with the project action(s) anyways?

This error also occured when I tried to update the Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility package. Does anybody know what is causing this issue? I don't quite get what the error is saying even after some research, and I couldn't find anyone else with this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> The nuget operation failed due to one or more packages being incompatible with your project

That because in the Visual Studio 2017 15.3:

> You had two ways to target `.NET Standard`: one was via letting a PCL
>   target .NET Standard. The other was via the new `.NET Standard`
>   project type. NuGet team disabled the UI for letting a **PCL** target
>   `.NET Standard` because it never worked well. It sounds like we’ve
>   accidentally broken something else that affects existing projects.
>
> However, you can use the `.NET Standard` project type, i.e. **File** |
>   **New Project** | **.NET Standard** | **Class Library (.NET Standard)** to target .NET Standard 1.x/2.x, which can still be
>   consumed from .NET Core 1.x/2.x.

Check the blog [Announcing .NET Standard 2.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-net-standard-2-0/) for some details

Hope this helps.